# How to get current month in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to add a custom column in power bi by this query:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "IsCurrentMonth",  if(Date.Month([Timestamp])=Date.Month(NOW())) then "Current Month" else "Other")
```

but the result is:

```
Expression.Error: The name 'NOW' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

so how can I get the current month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need is `DateTime.LocalNow`

So your query step becomes:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "IsCurrentMonth",  if(Date.Month([Timestamp])=Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())) then "Current Month" else "Other")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a column

[image]

and do this:

```
Column = if(MONTH('Date'[Date])=Month(NOW()), "Current Month", "Other")
```

Comment: You should use DateTime.LocalNow() like the comment above .. but thanks anyway bro